# Как переменная стала функцией?

Tags: javascript

```js
function makeBuffer() {
  var text = '';

  return function(piece) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) { // вызов без аргументов
      return text;
    }
    text += piece;
  };
};

var buffer = makeBuffer();

// добавить значения к буферу
buffer('Замыкания');
buffer(' Использовать');
buffer(' Нужно!');
alert( buffer() ); // 'Замыкания Использовать Нужно!'
```

как buffer стала функцией ? если мы в переменную возвращаем функцию она становится функцией ? Если да, то это fynction expression ?

Comment: Переменная остается переменной, а возможности по ее использованию зависят исключительно от категории сущности, на которую переменная ссылается в данный момент. `var wat; console.log(typeof wat); function myFunction() {} wat = myFunction; console.log(typeof wat); wat = 3; console.log(typeof wat); wat = "234"; console.log(typeof wat);` выведет `undefined function number string` - тип того, на что переменная ссылается

Comment: @VTT  я правильно понял  в переменную buffer мы передаем  function makeBuffer() у нее нет параметров при вызове buffer ('замыкания') мы передаем ей параметры. У function makeBuffer() внутри function(piece) где нет переменной text благодаря [[scope]]  она ищет у makeBuffer() у нет параметров, но мы ее вызвали  и передали ('замыкания') которое попадает в псевдомассив arguments откуда  function(piece) ее извлекает ?

Comment: @xes, нет, в переменную buffer мы передаем `результат вызова (return)` function makeBuffer()

Comment: @Руслан да верно мы передаем ей что возвращает return в данном случае функцию, а дальше я правильно написал ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В переменную `buffer` записано значение которое вернется из функции `makeBuffer`, а из функции `makeBuffer` возвращается функция. И, да, это замыкание.

А еще этот пример можно записать так:

```js
var buffer = function() {
 var text = '';

 return function(piece) {
  if (arguments.length == 0) { // вызов без аргументов
   return text;
  }
  text += piece;
 }
}();

// добавить значения к буферу
buffer('Замыкания');
buffer(' Использовать');
buffer(' Нужно!');
alert(buffer()); // 'Замыкания Использовать Нужно!'
```

Comment: в функции buffer  нет параметров, а тут мы ей передаем buffer('Замыкания'); как тогда в alerte ('Замыкания Использовать Нужно!')  ?

Comment: @xes, тут это хорошо объясняют: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpIxGwFz0Xs&t=0s&index=16&list=PL363QX7S8MfSxcHzvkNEqMYbOyhLeWwem

Comment: возвращаясь к моему вопросу грубо говоря если мы передаем buffer('Замыкания') это было бы как просто переменная  var  buffer = 'замыкания' верно ?

Comment: @xes, если не вдаваться в детали и судить по результату, то можно сказать, что, да, вы правы... ноооооо нет. Это все еще функция, просто она вернет содержимое переменной `text`, которая находится в той функции где возвращается та функция где мы конкатенируем аргументы возвращаемой функции. конечно это произойдет если мы вызовем функцию без аргументов...

Comment: вот так как я это понял работает;             я правильно понял в переменную buffer мы передаем function makeBuffer() у нее нет параметров при вызове buffer ('замыкания') мы передаем ей параметры. У function makeBuffer() внутри function(piece) где нет переменной text благодаря [[scope]] она ищет у makeBuffer() у нет параметров, но мы ее вызвали и передали ('замыкания') которое попадает в псевдомассив arguments откуда function(piece) ее извлекает ?

Comment: @xes, нет, в переменную buffer мы передаем `результат вызова (return)` function makeBuffer()

Comment: да верно мы передаем ей что возвращает return в данном случае функцию, а дальше я правильно написал ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87471/discussion-between--and-xes).